# "jmp run" opens firefox but does not opens any url

Tags: node.js, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I want to create a Firefox addon. Based on this page [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Modifying_Web_Pages_Based_on_URL) 
I want to filter a URL.The problem is when I use jpm run command which opens a new instance of Firefox, the instance does not opens any URL at all. I even used an empty index.js file and the problem still remains

Comment: Success, filter works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opened instance proxy is set to "Use system proxy settings" so the website may not be opened.

Answer (score 0):

`jpm run` just opens a Firefox instance. You must browse to the url you want to check.

Or you can add this code to your `index.js`:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example.com");
```

but be aware that this code will be executed every time you addon loads so you should remove it before publishing your add-on because it'd be very annoying.

Comment: I browse but nothing happens. It exactly do nothing when I enter url in address bar and press Enter or Go!

Comment: That's a different problem. Please open another question and show the relevant parts of your code. If we didn't see the code we can't help.